# Evaluation/Analysis design advice

Tags: causality, research-design

This is industry related stuff, so I'm not thrilled about being in this position and could just use any helpful other opinions.

My company has a program where we provide extra dollars to a hospital to help them see more of our members, known as supplemental funding. This has been around long before I've been there and is more legally complicated than you could even imagine.
Recently my executives have decided that I need to demonstrate the effectiveness of those dollars being spent in terms of increasing access for our members (this is operationally defined, not a big deal here), and we can get tracking to the level of which clinic in the hopsital those dollars go to. Seems not too difficult in some ways right, we of course don't have randomization but we can at least see where the dollars are going each year, and look at metrics around access to care, see how they vary between places getting dollars and not, and so on. I understand how hard this is to answer properly even in this set up, but I've settled into accepting that very rarely do the people I work for care about that level of scrutiny in inference.

Here is the issue. I just recently learned these dollars are NOT paid as a "treatment" or intervention, with the idea being for example, here is 50k go spend it to improve access for our members. Instead they are given as a reward. In other words, the money is distributed based on which clinics increased most in seeing our members, but once they get the money, there is no requirement to keep moving that trend forward in future years. So quite literally the payments are a response to the improved access, I can't think of how it could be more confounded. Is there any reasonable statistical way to evaluate the impact of this payment scheme on member access, or is it just unintelligible here to think of the payments as causing outcomes, when they are in fact the effect not the cause? Any outside perspective is welcome. Thanks!